# remove class style property using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

In my project, I have `card-footer` class and I want to remove his style `background-color` property using the javascript. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this function?

***This is my html tag***

```
 <div class="card-footer">
   <a name="" id="" class="btn btn-light" href="{{ route('posts.index') }}" role="button">Cancel</a>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Create</button>
 </div>
```

***script part***

```
   <script>
       (function removeProp()
        {
            const cardFooter = document.querySelector(".card-footer");
            cardFooter.style.removeProperty('background-color');
        })();
    </script>
```

Did I miss something or else?

Comment: Just apply another class to div with CSS rule ```background-color: none !important```.

Answer (score 2):

The `style` property addresses **only** rules applied directly to the element (e.g. with the style attribute).

It does not address rules from anywhere else in the cascade.

If you want to modify those, you’ll need to use the [CSS Object Model](https://css-tricks.com/an-introduction-and-guide-to-the-css-object-model-cssom/#the-cssstylesheet-interface) to access the rule set containing them.

Alternatively, if you want to modify the value for a *particular element* you could set a **new** value using the `style` property.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use that class and want to update the element with new class rule you can use below code. or you can simply remove the footer class.

```js
 (function removeProp()
        {
            const cardFooter = document.querySelector(".card-footer");
            cardFooter.classList.remove('card-footer');
            // you may add another class to change style and define you custom css class rules which you want to apply to cardFooter.
            cardFooter.classList.add('custom-card-footer');
        })();
```

```css
.card-footer{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.custom-card-footer{
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-footer">
   <a name="" id="" class="btn btn-light" href="{{ route('posts.index') }}" role="button">Cancel</a>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Create</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: SO that's mean I can not chagne the style property?

Comment: so I have to add new class

Comment: there are two ways to do this. remove the default class like i did and add style/properties to your element or define a css class and define style/properties there. the latter part gives you more control as you can add/remove css style by just updating the css class instead of updating the JS code.

Answer (score 0):

You can have style assigned to the class **or** to element.

If you have in css

```
.card-footer {
   background-color: ...
}
```

then you need to remove class by:

```
document.querySelector(".card-footer").classList.remove('card-footer')
```

You can also find `style` element in HTML by:

```
document.querySelector("style").textContent = ... <-- new css without  `background-color` of your `card-footer` class
```

Simples possible solution is provide two classes with separated responsibility

for example:

```
.card-footer { all styles out of bg color } 
.card-bg { backgroud-color: ... }
```

And then remove class by `classList` interface.